# How to change the default AWS EMR Step Log Path i.e. /mnt/var/log/hadoop/ to /home/hadoop/my/path

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

When an EMR Step runs in EMR cluster, it logs all the job's activity under its default path as below:

```
/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps
```

How to change this path to some custom location, for ex: `/home/hadoop/my/path/steps`

is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot change the default log location of steps, but you can add logging in your application to write to specific location

Comment: Are you sure about this,? any reference/documentation to this? if yes, request you to pls share so that we can have full-proof to this concept and can accept your answer , Thanks

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-manage-view-web-log-files.html It doesn't say anywhere that you can change the default step run log location.